# Rails 3: Sorting by many strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

I have multiple strings that are all number values. They are all inside the same db table. Is there a way to join them all and sort by the highest number?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
:include => :word_one_value, :word_two_value, :word_three_value, :sort_by => "sum ASC"
```

Comment: Why do you have string values that are actually numbers in first place?

Comment: @ismaelga I'm still learning. I've got many other strings and these are number values to them. For instance I've got :word_one, :word_two, :word_three -- these are the numbers that go along with them without creating overgrown tables in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql:

```
Foo.order '(convert(word_one, unsigned) +
            convert(word_two, unsigned) +
            convert(word_three, unsigned))'
```

In ActiveRecord:

```
Foo.all.sort_by do |f| 
  %w[one two three].sum { |n| f.send("word_#{n}").to_i } 
end
```

Or if these fields are inside Foo:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.sorted_by_sum_of_words
      order '(convert(word_one, unsigned) +
              convert(word_two, unsigned) +
              convert(word_three, unsigned))'
    end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @foos = Foo.sorted_by_sum_of_words        
  end
end
```

The conversions are unnecessary if you store numbers in number columns.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I appreciate it! I can't seem to figure out the second ActiveRecord example inside my controller action. My controller action looks like this: @ethos = user.ethos